# What is f(2) in the following code?

Tags: matlab, octave

The code (written in Octave) is:

```
x=1:2:5;
y=1:1:3;
z=1:0.1:1.2;
f=[x+y+z,x.^2+z;sin(x.*y.*z),cos(x)];
h=x(2)-x(1);
xFor=x(1:end-1);
dffor=(f(2:end)-f(1:end-1))/h;
f(2) 
dffor
```

The output I get is

```
Hello World
ans = 0.84147
dffor = -1.07926  2.62926  -2.89423  4.44423  4.77985  -5.54500  13.59500  -12.95817
```

I do not understand some of the code. What does `f(2)` evaluate?

I actually want to get the numerical derivative of the matrix with respect to `x`. I thought this was the method of forward differences. Also, why am I getting a `[1x11]` matrix as the output for `dffor`, which is supposed to be the numerical differentiation matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, `f` is a 2D matrix in your code (`size [2,6]`) and I assume you meant to have a vector (`size [1,12]`).

`dffor` is indeed the forward diff. and it has 11 elements (rather than 12 as `f`) because it has the differences between each consequent pair of `f`: each element is used twice except for the first and last: `(10*2 + 1 + 1)/2 = 11`.

`f(2)` is just the second element of `f` which equals `x(2) + y(2) + z(2)`

Comment: actually, I wanted to numerically partially differentiate the matrixwith respect to x. What is the code that should be written?

Comment: if you want to differentiate the `f`'s **rows** do `dffor=(f(:,2:end)-f(:,1:end-1))./h;`. when doing `f(2)` you're just accessing a **single** element in the matrix, in your case it's like doing `f(2,1)`. if you want to access the entire row or column do `f(2,:)` or `f(:,2)`.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks. by differentiating f's rows, you mean the entire matrix, right?

Comment: it's the entire matrix anyway, just depends along which dimension you're differentiating